# Semaphore in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatchsemaphore

I am facing an issue in using semaphores on iOS.
I am implementing a feature to execute a series of async methods sequentially, one after another in order.

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
semaphore.wait()
performFirstTask {
   semaphore.signal
}

semaphore.wait()
performSecondTask {
   semaphore.signal
}

semaphore.wait()
performThirdTask {
   semaphore.signal
}
```

So this is working as expected, but the issue comes if the user moves away from the screen in the wait state, so when the callback from a particular task fires, the view might have deallocated, which is causing a crash,
Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue, I am not seeing any way to release the semaphores.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use semaphores.

Comment: use OperationQueue instead. Or async/await if it fits

Comment: I tried using operationqueue , but it seems to execute in parallel, I am not sure how to initiate the second task after the completion of the first one.. Can you please help me with a sample

Comment: You have to set the max concurrency to 1.

Comment: Or why not just use a DispatchQueue, they are serial by default (when you create them from scratch).

Comment: DispatchQueue also tried , but the issue is I want the second task to start only after the completion of first one , and in that order

Comment: Yep, that's what a serial DispatchQueue does. This has "xy question" written all over it.

Comment: Switch to `async await`, this stuff is over complicated and prone to bugs https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132

Comment: @matt - FWIW, I did try to get him to volunteer more information about the underlying problem in [his last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73293393/1271826), but he seemed reluctant to go there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us imagine that you decided to adopt Swift concurrency, rather than using semaphores. So, what would this look like with `async`-`await`?

Let us imagine for a second that you refactored `performFirstTask`, `performSecondTask`, and `performThirdTask` to adopt Swift concurrency. Then, you eliminate the semaphore completely, and your fifteen lines of code are reduced to:

```swift
Task {
    await performFirstTask()
    await performSecondTask()
    await performThirdTask()
}
```

That performs those three asynchronous tasks sequentially, but avoids all of the downsides of semaphores. The whole idea of `async`-`await` is that you can represent dependencies between a series of asynchronous tasks very elegantly.

Now, generally you would refactor the `performXXXTask` methods to adopt Swift concurrency. Alternatively, you could also just write `async` “wrapper” functions for them, e.g.:

```swift
func performFirstTask() async {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        performFirstTask() {
            continuation.resume(returning: ())
        }
    }
}
```

That is an `async` rendition of `performFirstTask` that calls the completion handler rendition.

However you decide to do it (refactor these three methods or just write wrappers for them), Swift concurrency simplifies the process greatly. See WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/) for more examples about how to convert legacy code to adopt Swift concurrency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just wondering how should I do if `performSecondTask()` could be called by external objects, not at a certain timing, such as always following `performFirstTask`. And I still want task2 to wait till task1 finishes

Comment: You could use `Task` object to keep track of first task, that way independent calls to perform second and third tasks could await the result of this first one. E.g., https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/bc5712e8c185848962eafe07d5137fa8. If you still have questions about that, rather then posting them in comments here, please either post them under that gist, or post your own Stack Overflow question.

Comment: the gist is awesome, thank you very much for your prompt and detailed reply

Answer (score 8):

This semaphore-based code should be retired. Nowadays we would use the `async`-`await` of [Swift concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html). See WWDC 2021 video [Meet async/await in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132), as well as the other videos referenced on that page.

If you were not considering Swift concurrency for some reason (i.e., you need to support OS versions that don’t support `async`-`await`), you might consider [Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/), or custom asynchronous [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) subclass, or a number of third party solutions (e.g., promises or futures). But nowadays, semaphores are an anti-pattern.

Using semaphores has a number of problems:

- It is inefficient (as it unnecessarily ties up a thread);
- It introduces deadlock risks if not careful;
- It can result in substandard UX and/or watchdog process killing your app if you do this on the main thread.

---

That having been said, the problem is likely that your semaphore is deallocated when it has a value less than it was when it was created (e.g., you created it with a value of `1` and may have been `0` when it was deallocated). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70458886/1271826.

You can avoid this problem by starting with a value of zero. To do this, you either need to:

1. Remove the first `wait`:

   ```swift
   let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)   // not 1

   // semaphore.wait()
   performFirstTask {
      semaphore.signal()
   }

   semaphore.wait()
   performSecondTask {
      semaphore.signal()
   }

   …
   ```
2. Or if you need that first `wait`, just do a preemptive `signal`:

   ```swift
   let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)    // not 1
   semaphore.signal()                             // now bump it up to 1

   semaphore.wait()
   performFirstTask {
      semaphore.signal()
   }

   semaphore.wait()
   performSecondTask {
      semaphore.signal()
   }

   …
   ```

Again, you should retire the use of semaphores entirely, but if you must, you can use either of the two techniques to make sure that the count when it is deallocated is not less than it was when it was initialized.