# How to implement an asynchronous queue in Swift concurrency?

Tags: swift, async-await, semaphore, swift-concurrency, dispatchsemaphore

Background: I am familiar with concurrency using Locks and Semaphores, and am learning Swift's new concurrency features.

Here is a simplified example of an asynchronous queue in Swift using DispatchSemaphore:

```swift
class AsynchronousQueue {
    var data: [MyDataType] = []
    var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    
    func push(data: MyData) {
        data.append(data)
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    func pop() -> MyData {
        semaphore.wait()
        return data.popLast()
    }
}
```

Note that this is a little bit oversimplified - I will also want to restrict the editing of the data array such that its not mutated by two threads at the same time, which can be accomplished with Locks, or with Actors.  I also may want to send some sort of "cancel" signal, which also is a relatively small change.

The piece that I am not sure how to accomplish with Swift Concurrency is the role that the Semaphore plays here.  I want `pop()` to return immediately if data is available, or to wait, potentially indefinitely, if data is unavailable.

I have encountered a lot of posts discouraging the use of Semaphores at all in modern Swift, code, but I have not seen an example of how to do this kind of waiting with Swift concurrency features (`await/async/actor`) that is not significantly more complicated than using a semaphore.

Note that `DispatchSemaphore` can't be used from within an `async` function, so it seems difficult to use the new `await/async/actor` features together with code based on `DispatchSemaphore`, which is why I ask.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://forums.swift.org/t/communicating-between-two-concurrent-tasks/54240/5

Comment: Try just changing your `class` to an `actor` or `global actor` since you have a mutable variable, semaphores aren't needed because `actor` does this by default. The old `Dispatch` work in terms of threads the new concurrency work in terms of actors, that is why they aren't compatible.

Comment: @Sweeper it looks like AsyncStream is something along the lines of an existing implementation of the buffer in my example.  Good to know it exists, but I'd still like to know how to implement something like this using Swift Concurrency primitives.  This kind of buffer is the classic example of what a semaphore is good for, but more complex situations exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, what you have described is a stack (or a LIFO queue).

Here is my implementation.

It supports `push`, blocking and non-blocking `pop` as well as `peek` and `cancel`.

`isEmpty` and `stackDepth` properties are available.

```
actor AsyncStack<Element> {
    private var storage = [Element]()
    private var awaiters = [CheckedContinuation<Element,Error>]()
    
    
    /// Push a new element onto the stack
    /// - Parameter newElement: The element to push
    /// - Returns: Void

    public func push(_ newElement: Element) async-> Void {
        if !awaiters.isEmpty {
            let awaiter = awaiters.removeFirst()
            awaiter.resume(returning: newElement)
        } else {
            storage.append(newElement)
        }
    }
    
    /// Pop the  element at the top of the stack or wait until an element becomes available
    /// - Returns: The popped element
    /// - Throws: An AsyncQueueError if the waiting pop is cancelled

    public func popOrWait() async throws -> Element {
        if let element = storage.popLast() {
            return element
        }
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            awaiters.append(continuation)
        }
    }
    
    /// Pop an element from the top of the stack if possible
    /// - Returns: An element or nil if the stack is empty

    public func pop() async -> Element? {
        return storage.popLast()
    }
    
    /// Return the element at the top of the stack, if any, without removing it
    /// - Returns: The element a the top of the stack or nil
    public func peek() async -> Element? {
        return storage.last
    }
    
    /// True if the stack is empty

    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        get async {
            return storage.isEmpty
        }
    }

    /// Current stack depth

    public var stackDepth: Int {
        get async {
            return storage.count
        }
    }
    
    /// Cancel all pending popOrWait operations.
    /// Pending operations will throw `AsyncQueue.OperationCancelled`
    /// - Returns: Void

    public func cancel() async -> Void {
        for awaiter in awaiters {
            awaiter.resume(throwing: AsyncQueueError.OperationCancelled)
        }
        awaiters.removeAll()
    }
    
    public enum AsyncQueueError: Error {
        case OperationCancelled
    }
}
```

I have used a [`CheckedContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/checkedcontinuation) to block the `pop` operation if the stack is empty.  The continuations are held in their own array to allow for multiple, blocked "poppers".  The `cancel` operation cancels all outstanding `popOrWait` operations.  The cancelled calls will `throw`.

Blocked `pop` operations complete in FIFO order.

Comment: This looks very similar to an implementation of a semaphore or condition variable using a mutex.  This should work, but is rather unsatisfying in that it is reinventing the wheel (reimplementing the semaphore).

Comment: I guess an actor is like a mutex. A continuation is more commonly called a *promise*. Mutexes and semaphores are low-level concurrency tools. Swift concurrency provides more abstracted tools. If you want to use a semaphore then stick with a GCD implementation and use a semaphore.

Comment: While there is a little bit of code required to implement the continuation queuing the advantages are that there is no risk of blocking a thread, there is no risk of deadlock and it was easy to implement the `cancel` operation. With a DispatchSemaphore you would have to resort to some sort of time out/check for cancelled/retry logic that may well introduce bugs with the ordering of pops (the `semaphore.wait` operations may become reordered). It would also need some sort of trade off in the selection of a time-out value to select between overhead and latency

Comment: Rob summarises the case against semaphores [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73533988/3418066)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "no risk of blocking a thread" since "blocking a thread" is specifically the goal (making a thread wait until data is available).

Comment: I saw that other question but that case against semaphores is pretty specific to the example given, which fits the async/await style a lot better than this example.

Comment: I think I'm convinced this answer is "the correct" way to do it, stemming from continuations being a concurrency primitive roughly equivalent to a condition variable or semaphore (in that you can implement e.g. a semaphore with a continuation or visa versa).

I still don't know why Apple doesn't provide a "Swift Concurrency" version of a semaphore.

Comment: I just noticed your comment about thread blocking; this is a very important distinction between Swift async/await concurrency and a DispatchSemaphore. `await` blocks execution but it does so at the Swift level. it does not block the underlying thread, so that thread is available to perform other work. Threads are a limited resource. A DispatchSemaphore blocks the underlying thread and that thread is not available to perform other work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255626/discussion-between-wolflink-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own "Queue" by creating a `globalActor`

```
@globalActor
struct MySpecialQueue {
    static var shared: MySpecialActor = .init()
    
    typealias ActorType = MySpecialActor
    
    actor MySpecialActor {
        
    }
}
```

Then you can use `@MySpecialQueue` whenever you want to "schedule" something.

```
class MyService {
    private (set) var data: [String] = []
    
    @MySpecialQueue func push(data: String) {
        print(#function)
        for _ in 0...10000000 {
            //im busy
        }
        
        self.data.append(data)
    }
    
    @MySpecialQueue func pop() -> String? {
        print(#function)
        return data.popLast()
    }
}
```

Notice that doing an `await` inside the Actor, the Actor is released to do the next thing. So, if you replace

```
    @MySpecialQueue func push(data: String) {
        print(#function)
        for _ in 0...10000000 {
            //im busy
        }
        
        self.data.append(data)
    }
```

for something like

```
    @MySpecialQueue func push(data: String) async {
        print(#function)
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(10))
        
        self.data.append(data)
    }
```

The actor will `pop` before the `push`es are done.

Comment: Won't this simply throw an error if pop is called when the queue is empty, instead of waiting for data?

Comment: Using a global actor doesn't scale very well as the data structure is coupled to the global actor.  I think it is better to use an `actor` so that the stack/queue is self contained and you can have as many as you want of them

Comment: @WolfLink no pop last is safe