# Suspending Network Request When Refresh Token

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I have this Network Manager class

```
class NetworkService: NetworkRequestServicing {

private let tokenService: TokenServicing
private let httpClient: HTTPClient

weak var delegate: TokenDelegate?

public init(httpClient: HTTPClient, tokenService: TokenServicing) {
    self.httpClient = httpClient
    self.tokenService = tokenService
}

func sendAuthenticatedRequest<T: Decodable>(request: Request,
                                            responseModel: T.Type,
                                            isFormData: Bool,
                                            retryTimes: Int,
                                            additionalHeaders: [String: String]?) async -> Result<T, RequestError> {

    let result = await httpClient.sendRequest(request: request,
                                              responseModel: responseModel,
                                              retryTimes: retryTimes,
                                              additionalHeaders: additionalHeaders,
                                              isFormData: isFormData)
    switch result {
    case .success:
        return result
    case .failure(let error):
        if case RequestError.unauthorized = error {
            return await refresh(request: request, responseModel: responseModel)
        } else {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}

private func refresh<T: Decodable>(request: Request,
                                   responseModel: T.Type,
                                   isFormData: Bool = false,
                                   sendBinaryRequest: ((Request) async -> Result<T, RequestError>)? = nil) async -> Result<T, RequestError> {
    print("New Refresh Token needed")

    guard let expiryDate = tokenService.getRefreshExpiryDate(),
          expiryDate > .now else {
        print("RefreshToken not valid")
        return await .failure(reLogin())
    }

    guard tokenService.getRefreshToken() != nil else {
        print("No refresh token available -> User must ReLogin")
        return await .failure(reLogin())
    }

    let numberOfRetries = 3
    for failedRefreshAttempts in 1...numberOfRetries {
        let result = await tokenService.tokenRefresh()

        switch result {
        case .success:
            print("Refresh Tokens succeeded")
            await sendRefreshToDelegates()
            if let sendBinaryRequest = sendBinaryRequest {
                return await sendBinaryRequest(request)
            } else {
                return await httpClient.sendRequest(request: request, responseModel: responseModel,
                                                    isFormData: isFormData)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("\(failedRefreshAttempts). attempt of refreshing the tokens failed due to \(error)")
        }

         try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000) // 1 second
    }

    return await .failure(reLogin())
}
```

Which works fine, but I need to suspend new requests that may come during the refresh request is doing its work , to avoid multiple triggers of tokens and save unneeded network calls.

I tried to use DispatchSemaphore. but it didn't really work out with the async method, and seems from the first glimpse that it will slow down my general network requests, cause it will do one at a time.

I also tried to achieve it, by storing requests in an array , but it was quite complex to scale.

Is there another solution that can be used?

Comment: You can't combine GCD techniques, such as DispatchSemaphores with async/await. You should create an async function in your TokenService that returns the access token. This function can use the refresh token if required. Implement queuing so that subsequent requests for a token are blocked until the previous request has been completed. In the normal course, the access token will be returned immediately, but when a new access token is required, the requests will wait until the new token is available

Comment: The technique I used with a checked continuation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77285570/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-queue-in-swift-concurrency/77287091#77287091) will be useful.